# Performance of a non-contiguous pointer array pointing to a one dimensional target array in fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran2008

I have a code in which a one-dimensional array `R` is used which has `3N` elements. You can think of it as the position vector of `N` particles, such that `R=[r1x,r1y,r1z,r2x,r2y,...]`. Note that the pattern should be defined as this for concise usage of the array.

In sections of the code, I need to perform some operations only on the x-coordinates. I am currently using something like this:

```
Rx => R(1:3N-2:3)
```

and `Rx` is subsequently used in the operations. This makes the access non-contiguous but I was wondering if I can hope for a way to vectorize the operations. Alternatively, one may use OMP with a loop over the particles. I want to get the expert's idea on this matter and particularly the best possible practice performance-wise.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran], only few people follow fortran2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have your cake and eat it too.  If you want to make strided access to non-contiguous array elements you're going to pay a price in performance.  For small arrays, in which all the elements fit into cache, you'll probably never notice the price.  For larger arrays you'll do a lot more data movement through cache than if you step through array elements one-by-one in memory-layout order.  Using pointers to non-contiguous array sections doesn't magically alter these facts (as you seem to be aware).

So what you do is what Fortran programmers have always done, optimise the memory layout of your arrays for the most common access pattern. In your case many of us would have either a `3,x` rank-2 array or a `x,3` one depending on whether accessing all the `x` (or `y` or `z`) elements together was more frequent than accessing particle-by-particle.

Sometimes it's worth transposing an array prior to operations on elements in non-memory-layout order.  Sometimes it's even worth holding the same data twice, once in one order, once in the other.  But you're going to have to figure out which is the best solution for your program, we don't have all the facts necessary to provide a high-quality recommendation.  If it matters to you, then it should matter enough for you to conduct some tests and develop a quantified view of the situation.

You pays your money and you makes your choice.

Comment: Thanks Mark. There are useful hints in your answer. The fact in my code is that the (3,:) layout is a must, since the largest scale operations are done with the global vector R. I am not sure if I get the correct conclusion from your first paragraph, so the Rx pointer to a large R would have the advantage of sending a big chunk of array to cache, which result in better usage of cache?

Comment: And there is no definite recommendation about selecting either element-wise operations (parallelized using OMP) or a pointer pointing to the a noncontinuous section. Further, I was also willing to make sure if there won't be any auto-vectorization on the Rx, as I mentioned in the original question. thanks again.

Comment: *so the Rx pointer to a large R would have the advantage of sending a big chunk of array to cache*  Either I misunderstand you or you misunderstand me.  When a memory location is loaded to cache a whole cache line of memory locations (the one referenced and its neighbours) is loaded.  How many are loaded depends on the size of a cache line.  If your array is laid out as you show us and your pointer Rx is as specified you will read approximately 3 times as many lines into cache than you would if Rx pointed to contiguous memory.